# Use Astro component in client-side

Tags: web-component, astrojs

I have this component

```
---
import Siren from '@components/Icons/Siren.astro';
import type { IJob } from '@util/job.interface';

export interface Props extends IJob{}
const Job=Astro.props
const {company, title, email, type, deadline, skills, link, logo,close=false }=Job
const tags=skills.split(",")
---

<div class='transition ease-in-out delay-150 flex overflow-hidden border border-zinc-300 rounded-md ring-slate-800  shadow-md duration-300 hover:border-zinc-500 hover:shadow-lg hover:scale-105'>
        <img src={logo} onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='/images/joblogo.png'" alt="logo" class=" bg-white w-28 sm:w-32 object-cover object-center">
        <div class="flex flex-col text-[#002838] mx-2 my-2 sm:mx-4 sm:my-4 text-sm w-full">
            <h1 class="font-bold">{title}</h1>
            <div class="text-xs mt-1">
                <h2 class="font-medium mt-1">{company}</h2>
                <p class="mb-1">{type}</p>
                <p class={close && 'text-[#ED0000] flex relative'}>Apply before: {deadline} {close && 
                    <span class="flex">
                        <span class="animate-ping mx-[0.68rem] absolute inline-flex h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-[#ED0000] opacity-75"></span>
                        <span class="relative mx-2 -my-1"><Siren/></span>
                    </span>
                }
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex mt-6 items-center">
                <ul class="flex flex-wrap gap-2 text-[8px] sm:text-xs font-medium">
                    {tags.map(tag=>{
                        return <li class="rounded-sm bg-[#002838] text-white text-start px-1 hover:bg-[#00283896] duration-150">{tag}</li>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
            {
                link && <button 
            type="button" class="self-end mt-4 rounded-lg bg-[#0374E2] text-white w-16 sm:w-20 item-center text-md h-6 hover:text-zinc-800 hover:bg-accent duration-150 hover:shadow-md">
                <a href={link} target="_blank">Apply</a>
            </button>
            }
            {
                email && 
            <button 
            type="button" onclick={`openModal("${email}")`} class="self-end mt-4 rounded-lg bg-[#0374E2] text-white w-16 sm:w-20 item-center text-md h-6 hover:text-zinc-800 hover:bg-accent duration-150 hover:shadow-md">
                Apply
            </button>
            
            }
            
        </div>
</div>
```

I want to get a data from an api, and render this component using vanilla js

I know that I can do that from server side, but I'm trying to enable search, so I have to call the api again and render the new data that, back and there's no way to interact with the server again as the astro just run this code on the build time only

so any solution ?

I'm trying to extend my astro component, but I don't know how to pass my props via HTML custom element

Answer (score 1):

Astro components don't render client side, as explained in their docs [here](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-components/):

> The most important thing to know about Astro components is that they don’t render on the client. They render to HTML either at build-time or on-demand using server-side rendering (SSR). You can include JavaScript code inside of your component frontmatter, and all of it will be stripped from the final page sent to your users’ browsers. The result is a faster site, with zero JavaScript footprint added by default.

An alternative could be to create the component manually with client-side js, but it cannot be a `.astro` component. Learn more about SSR here: https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/server-side-rendering/#configure-server-or-hybrid.
Some of your pages can still be statically rendered.

One thing I haven't looked into that *might* be possible is using something like server components from a React integration, but I think that would be more trouble than it's worth, if possible at all.

I hope this was helpful.